# Insert Cell after unequal value, copy, then delete inserted rows

Tags: loops, excel, vba

Hi there I have created the following two macros however it is inserting a row after the last cell with data.  I believe this is a result of my loop condition being `Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""`.  I would like to have the loop stop at the last cell with data.

I tried using variables `Do Until Loop_Long = LastRow` but this did not work for me.

All I would like is to have a macro insert a row between cells with unlike data.  Then a macro that will find empty cells in the column,the ones we previously inserted, and then delete the row.

As outlined above the issue is it is inserting an extra row and not deleting it, if you put values all the way down column B after your data in column A you will see what I mean.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
'Insert Blank Row Between Names
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Range("A1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
 Loop
End Sub

Sub Macro2()

Dim LastRow As Long

'Delete Inserted Rows
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LastRow).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Range("A1")
    If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Value Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: First, what is your goal here, becuase it seems like you're defeating the purpose by deleting rows you just created... Second, this code works fine for me. Are you hoping to skip the row if there's data in column B?

Comment: @ARich example A1:A9 are all different names.  I want to put a space between them then copy that and paste it somewhere else, then remove the row that was inserted. This code inserts a row after the last cell with a name but does not delete it. After running this code A18 is a blank row, this row should not be inserted, and then running the delete macro it ends up with A10 being a blank row.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told me, the below code should work for you (and it better follows best practices)... Have you considered copying the data as is and then inserting the rows once you've pasted the data to the new location? That would cut out a step.

```
Option Explicit
'Declare module-level variables.
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim NameRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Sub test()
'Add blank rows.
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Set NameRng = sht.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

For Each Cell In NameRng
    If Cell <> Cell.Offset(1, 0) And Cell <> "" Then
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
Sub test2()
'Delete blank rows.
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Set NameRng = sht.Range("A1:A" & LastRow + 1)

For Each Cell In NameRng
    If Cell = "" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to insert the rows between the information before it is copied as I am concatinating a bunch of columns together so i cannot compare the cells after the paste as they will all be unique.  I have continued on for now without inserting the spaces, I will re-visit it after I have completed all the other aspects of the workbook.  Thanks for the input, it is appreciated.